# mysql stored procedure call

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a simple mysql query

```
select u.user_id, username, company_details_id, company_name, ut.user_type_id, role_type, street1, city_town, phone, email, website, create_date, update_date, isActive from users u 
join company_details cd on u.user_id = cd. user_id
join user_type ut on u.user_type_id=ut.user_type_id order by company_name asc;
```

I am trying to order the list as `ascending` or `descending` with reference to username or company_name etc. I want to pass the dynamic value after `order by` in the above query. It is working fine when i execute by hard-coding the values after `order by` but when I tried the same above query in `stored procedure` like this

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=root@localhost PROCEDURE reportAllClients(selectName varchar(100))
BEGIN
select u.user_id, username, company_details_id, company_name, ut.user_type_id, role_type, street1, city_town, phone, email, website, create_date, update_date, isActive from users u 
join company_details cd on u.user_id = cd. user_id
join user_type ut on u.user_type_id=ut.user_type_id order by selectName;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I called the stored procedure as `call reportAllClients('company_name desc');` but I am not getting the result as expected. It is always showing the same result whatever parameter I pass into the procedure. Is there any way around to view the list in `asc` or `desc` order with username, company_name etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE DEFINER=root@localhost PROCEDURE reportAllClients(selectName varchar(100))
```

should be

```
CREATE DEFINER=root@localhost PROCEDURE reportAllClients(IN selectName varchar(100))
```

Comment: I tried putting IN but didn't work. Is there any other problem rather than the above. I am unable to figure it out.

Comment: I hope your are passing a column name to the procedure, are you ?

Comment: Yes I'm passing the column name plus the order asc or desc. Please check above how I am calling the procedure. Am I doing it the wrong way? Thanks.

Comment: ohh.. you have to pass 2 parameters. desc should be passed seperately. right now it takes only the column name and ignores desc as they are seperate by a space.

Comment: Hey, I dont think it is possible to achieve what you are doing.. let some other guys comment.. :(